# Intent not sent to main activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have Login Activity which is main activity.
Second one is Register.
I am trying to send the email from register activity back to login activity after registration process however i can not get the value out of the intent.
I have noticed some filters in manifest at the main activity however not sure if it can cause such a problem.

Register activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Register.this, LoginPage.class);
myIntent.putExtra("registerEmail", mail);
Register.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("registerEmail");
    if (value!=null)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The value is always null when i get back to loginPage from Register and i am sure i did send contents to the intent in Register activity

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When from activity A you starts another activity (activity B), in order to return back a result to activity A, you should use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

However if your main activity is started using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, you can intercept the intent using `onNewIntent()` inside your main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("registerEmail");
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this, but didn't see the flag set anywhere :/

Comment: @user3607584 do you solve your problem using startActivityForResult() or onNewIntent() ?

Answer (score 1):

The intent filters you see in your manifest file are to indicate to the Android framework which activity should show when you first launch your app. Intent filters are not needed for common internal operations such as starting a new activity in your own app.

Your code looks ok otherwise. Can we see a bit more code from each class (e.g. where the intent is fired from)?

Comment: Yes i checked the mail and it was not null as i mentioned in my post. There has to be some kind of other catch. Thank you for clearing out the filters thingy

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should read the value registerEmail at onResume when you return to the login activity

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your going to want to use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) with an intent that the registration activity can identify and call sendResult(Intent intent) from the onDestroy method. With that intent you can bundle the data you need into it and from the LoginActivity override onActivityResult to get the bundle intent data.